# Understanding File History and child parent of a Patent

Tags: priority, continuation-in-part, child-application

In reference to the patent: [US20030154017](https://www.google.com/patents/US20030154017)

Priority date is 1996 and based on number the patent is in Application status, how come?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the File History of a patent or an application -  (filed/granted in US) - follow the steps shown here (as of September 2015)

1 - Search for USPTO Public Pair

2 - Go to the page shown below

[image]

Enter the captcha and press `Continue`

3 - Now enter the publication number-select that radio button and press `Search`

[image]

4 - Now select the `tab` that you want to read

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb. 23, 2005 patent application US20030154017 is abandoned. Please find **Image File Wrapper** using [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) and take a look at last document - **notice of abandonment**.

P.s. In [PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) enter 20030154017 as publication number to get access to the patent prosecution documents.

Comment: It would be great if you could include a bit about how you found this out, like where you went to find it and what list told you.

Comment: you can use "public pair" for this information- just google it, and then search the application number from there for the complete prosecution history